# Would it be faster to use a CSS Child Selector?

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

If we wanted to target a link within a paragraph, which selector would be more efficient/faster?

```
p a
```

or

```
p > a
```

Comment: I would suspect `p > a`, but probably by a negligible amount of time. What did your benchmark say?

Comment: For more, the child selector was not supported by ie6..

Comment: The only people who care about IE6 anymore today probably already know that.

Comment: There was an answer, now deleted, mentioning the fact that the two selectors do completely different things and therefore shouldn't be compared by performance alone. I don't see why it would be seen as "not useful" or irrelevant. Given the nature of `p` and `a` elements in HTML, the odds that you'll find yourself dealing with `a` elements that are `p a` but not `p > a` are not insignificant. And, based on the answer by Niels Keurentjes, I can guarantee that you'll encounter such a scenario long before this particular selector ever becomes a bottleneck.

Comment: The conclusion from my answer should indeed be - never solve problems before they appear. The likelihood of CSS ever becoming a realistic performance issue is so low that, even more than with all premature micro-optimization, the chance of bugs is simply not worth it. Write the correct declarations, and eliminate bottlenecks on a finished site when they start to appear. I think this question is more theoretical in nature though, and not a real intent to start preferring one over the other.

Answer (score 14):

The second is (extremely) marginally faster. CSS is handled in reverse by browsers, so both your rules are tested on all `a` elements on the page. For the second rule it only needs to test the direct parent, for the other one it would need to test the entire descendant chain.

In practice, the execution time difference won't be statistically significant until you get tens of thousands of these on a page with just as many lines of HTML.

Comment: You mean the entire ancestor chain, right? Sounds like I'm being picky but that confused me for a second.

Comment: I was referring to the descendant chain of the parent, but yes that is the same as the ancestor chain of the child.

Answer (score 13):

Let me show you the efficiency order of selectors, from fastest to the slowest, that's some conclusion from google:

1. id Selectors (#myid)
2. class Selectors (.myclassname)
3. tag Selectors (div,h1,p)
4. neighbour Selectors (h1+p)
5. children Selectors (ul>li）
6. descendant Selectors (li a)
7. star Selectors (*)
8. property Selectors (a[rel="external"])
9. pseudo class Selectors (a:hover,li:nth-child)

It might not be exactly right, and not being right for various of browsers, but still this order is available for reference. Hope it helps!

To see more about CSS performance, see: http://benfrain.com/css-performance-revisited-selectors-bloat-expensive-styles/

Comment: Why should I trust a random list of made-up stats, with some poor terminology to boot, as authoritative?

Comment: @BoltClock That might not be accurate for all browsers. And I just refer someone else's conclusion. For more to know about, see: http://benfrain.com/css-performance-revisited-selectors-bloat-expensive-styles/

Comment: If you're referring to something you did not write, you **need** to quote the copied content and cite the source within your answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing Don't wait for others to prompt you to link to the source after the fact, because someone will assume otherwise that you wrote it yourself (like I did earlier).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the problem @BoltClock, I've improved the answer and will more serious in the future.

Comment: @BoltClock I do so have an appreciation for your sarcastic remarks. Your implication is extremely clear that requires no elaboration whatsoever.