# CSS performance: descendent or two direct descendent selectors best?

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

Given the following HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a ...
```

**For the same set of declarations, which one of these two rule sets would be more advisable to use taking their performance into consideration?**

```
ul > li > a {
  color: black
}
```

```
ul a {
  color: black
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is that bad of a question to warrant down-votes. Maybe try improving the title on this. I'd be interested in seeing the answer. +1

Comment: not constructive enough to answer, in some context, the html code needs to design the css in order to apply. From the Dom CssDom and all doms in the browser, perhaps there is a technical way to 'talk' css in the most efficient way. But in the web agency or other contexts of lack of knowledge, you spend more time trying to fix why you page does not look the same from a navigator to another.

Comment: In your question add a variety of key selectors, like [li > div > p > a]  the same level has [li > div > span > a] or [li > p > a] to consider the number of different ways to target an element and the necessity to reduce the duplication ...

Comment: I think for a complex app is better to use classes like ".list, .list-item, .list-item-link

"Tag category rules should never contain a child selector"

Comment: This is also relevant to a good css-reset structure.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25734337/24874

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The most fundamental concept to learn is this rule filtering. The categories exist in order to filter out irrelevant rules (so the style system doesn’t waste time trying to match them).
>
> For example, if an element has an ID, then only ID rules that match the element’s ID will be checked. Only Class Rules for a class found on the element will be checked. Only tag rules that match the tag will be checked. Universal Rules will always be checked.

**Avoid the descendant selector**

> The descendant selector is a more expensive selector than a child selector

**BAD**(Descendant selector)
sets the text color to black whenever an 'a' occurs anywhere within an 'ul' element

```
 ul a {
  color: black
}
```

**BETTER Than above**(Child selector)
'a' element must be the child of an 'li' element; the 'li' element must be a child of an 'ul' element

```
 ul > li > a {
  color: black
}
```

**further reading [LINK](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2011/css-selector-performance-has-changed-for-the-better/)**

Comment: Cite this in your answer "The most fundamental concept to learn is this rule filtering. The categories exist in order to filter out irrelevant rules (so the style system doesn’t waste time trying to match them)." AND CLARIFY what you mean about 'avoiding' the descendant selector.

Comment: @MilchePatern yeh it is the important part ! I'll add

Comment: * { box-sizing: border-box; text-shadow: 2px 3px 9px #FF0000; text-shadow: 2px 3px 9px #FF0000, 1px 1px 9px #0000FF;text-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(255, 0,0,0.5;}

Comment: @MilchePatern It's mean if you can, don't use descendant-selectors

Comment: yah, was kidding .. all went fast while reading .. Mozzila dev link from David Hyatt is good. Was about "For instance, the performances are so bad, that descendant selectors are banned in Firefox' User Interface CSS, without a specific justification." ..

Comment: @MilchePatern *{} is most expensive selector :v haa haa

Comment: @alejandro make sure you select an answer if you're satisfied. it takes time to answer questions.

Comment: You may want to edit this to cite a more up to date source. From the linked document: "**Note:** This document was originally written in 2000. Much has changed when it comes to writing CSS that is fast"

Comment: @Shaggy The basics of CSS are still the same. Also, what has changed is actually worse for performance. Complex CSS3 selectors, etc. may be very convenient but are very slow in terms of pure speed. alejandro, to give a real example - around 3ms to target 2000 anchors in a large HTML document. This will vary depending on the browser and the hardware though. The impact will be likely larger on slow mobile phones and similar devices.