# html5 tag or div for perfomance

Tags: html, css

> Use HTML5 tags, these are new, better for SEO and well-structured for
>   debugging.

I have been using HTML5 tags as much as I can since I know about these tags. In my websites I have used almost tags. Apart from that, I have minimized the usage of tags and divs using more CSS rules such as children selector, descendant.

**I had been assuming - less usage of div would minimize code and performs better**

But while concerning about **perfomance** I found (fastest to lowest)

> 1. id Selectors (#myid)
> 2. class Selectors (.myclassname)
> 3. tag Selectors (div,h1,p)
> 4. neighbour Selectors (h1+p)
> 5. children Selectors (ul>li）
> 6. descendant Selectors (li a)
> 7. star Selectors (*)
> 8. property Selectors (a[rel="external"])
> 9. pseudo class Selectors (a:hover,li:nth-child)

**Infact, perfomance and speed comes first before SEO and coding readability.**

Let's ignore SEO, I am developing web based software, not need SEO. Actually it would be better if I do coding in well-structured manner,

I know it's easy for me to debug, but if it's usage compromises performance then **why use vast CSS rules, selection, new HTML5 tags, new trends ?** Just assign id and class to each element that you need.

For example, I have to select element that contains the text `Here you go`.

What I am doing in my project

```
article section:nth-child(2) aside:nth-child(1) section
```

Which is faster and better ?

Select according my project or select direct assigning single id `#section5`

**First way**

```
<article>
    <header>
    </header>
    <section>
        <aside>
            <section></section>
        </aside>
        <aside>
            <section></section>
        </aside>
    </section>
    <section>
        <aside>
            <section></section>
            <section>Here you go</section>
        </aside>
        <aside>
            <section></section>
        </aside>
    </section>
</article>
```

**Second way**

```
<div>
    <div id='header'>
    </header>
    <div id='section'>
        <div id='aside'>
            <div id='section1'></div>
        </div>
        <div id='aside1'>
            <div id='section2'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='section3'>
        <div id='aside2'>
            <div id='section4></div>
            <div id='section5'>Here you go</div>
        </aside>
        <div id='aside3'>
            <div id='section6'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

References

[Would it be faster to use a CSS Child Selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734337/would-it-be-faster-to-use-a-css-child-selector)

[Is CSS faster when you are specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421373/is-css-faster-when-you-are-specific)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second way would be faster talking about performances

```html
<div>
    <div id='header'>
    </header>
    <div id='section'>
        <div id='aside'>
            <div id='section1'></div>
        </div>
        <div id='aside1'>
            <div id='section2'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='section3'>
        <div id='aside2'>
            <div id='section4></div>
            <div id='section5'>Here you go</div>
        </aside>
        <div id='aside3'>
            <div id='section6'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However **using only IDs is not recommanded** as it can result in a lot of conflicts later during your project.
So I would recommand something like:

```html
<div>
    <header>
     <h1>This is your header</h1>
    </header>
    <div id='section1'>
        <aside>
            <div id='section1_part1'></div>
        </aside>
        <aside>
            <div id='section1_part2'></div>
        </aside>
    </div>
    <div id='section2'>
        <aside>
            <div id='section2_part1'></div>
            <div id='section2_part2'>Here you go</div>
        </aside>
        <aside>
            <div id='section3'></div>
        </aside>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean mixed usage of tags and divs

Comment: Exactly, and if never you have any css that repeat itself into various IDs, please use a `class` instead or in addition to yours IDs, a clean and reusable code should be the priority.